# Run group of test in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My application has some functions that are using httparty service to get data from another website. So it takes a lot of time when run the test for http functions.

```
- spec
-- services
--- http_request
---- test_http_a_spec.rb
---- test_http_b_spec.rb
--- component
---- test_component_c_spec.rb
---- test_component_d_spec.rb
--- models
---- test_model_e_spec.rb
```

So how can I run rspec test for all tests except the tests in `http_request` folder ?
Thanks

Comment: The other website is probably not the system you want to test. Have you considered using [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to stub the requests and / or [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to record and replay the HTTP traffic?

Comment: I'm a new Ruby guy (from Java). I will take a look at both libs you mention above. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You may want to tag your http tests with [rspec filters](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/filtering/exclusion-filters#exclude-a-group) and [rspec tags](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option#exclude-examples-with-a-simple-tag).

For example, in `spec/services/http_request/test_http_a_spec.rb`:

```
describe WhatEver
  describe 'Testing', http: true do
     it 'should work' do
       # ...
     end
  end
end
```

And then, run your tests with `rspec --tag ~http`. Tests with tag `http: true` will not be executed.

On the other hand, if your http tests are taking so long to execute, you may probably want to read [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests).

Comment: When I run rspec it showed:
bundle exec rspec -t ~http

zsh: no such user or named directory: http_request

Comment: rspec-core (3.4.4) & ruby "2.2.2"

Comment: @LeoLe This is related to `zsh`. Please, review [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3957). In summary, just run `noglob rspec -t ~http`.

Comment: same result !
noglob rspec -t ~http
zsh: no such user or named directory: http

Comment: Try using another shell. If the problem is solved, then it's related to `zsh`. If that's the case, you should open a new question.

Comment: Do you have any Shell suggestion for Rails dev ? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it still show "zsh" on my terminal :(